# Asynchronously get user data in facebook tab?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the php sdk, I check if a user inside a tab likes the corresponding page.

If i put the following code inside index.php and use that page as my page-tab-url,

```
<?php
require_once("facebook/facebook.php");

// Create our application instance
// (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1399475990283166',
  'secret' => 'mysercret',
  'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
echo $signed_request['page']['liked'];
?>
```

it outputs '1'.

I would like to achieve this asynchronously instead, so I put the php in a separate file and try to access it using ajax instead

```
$http.post('/facebook/likes.php').
    success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
    );
```

This sample is using angular, but what javascript library i'm using probably doesn't matter.

When I access the info with javascript Facebook doesn't seem to get the info that I liked the page. Adding a print_r($facebook); on the page I'm retreiving the same values as if i'm not in a facebook-tab:

```
(
    [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
    [appId:protected] => 1399475990283166
    [appSecret:protected] => 679fb0ab947c2b98e818f9240bc793da
    [user:protected] => 
    [signedRequest:protected] => 
    [state:protected] => 
    [accessToken:protected] => 
    [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
    [trustForwarded:protected] => 
)
```

Can I access theese values asynchronosly somehow?

Comment: _“I would like to achieve this asynchronously instead”_ – why? What would be the benefit of doing this “asynchronously” in a page tab app?

Comment: The page tab app contains a form. You are only suppose to be able to submit the form if you have liked the page.

Comment: So you check on app load, server-side, if the user has liked the page already – and if not, you do not give him the form in the first place, but a message instead that he is supposed to like the page first. Liking the page via the Like button on top will reload your app. This time, your check will find that he has liked the page, you present him with the form and let him submit it … no need to do anything asynchronously at all here.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're only logged as a Facebook application if you can access the `signed_request` token. This token is sent with the initial request (as a POST parameter), but isn't inside a cookie of anything.

The easiest thing with your actual code would be to re-send this signed request parameter with every ajax request you make so the server and Facebook SDK has access to that information.

But just to check if the user liked the current page. I'd suggest you print the data on the page directly so it is available from the start. Pseudo example:

```
<script>
  window.data = {};
  window.data.page_liked = <?= encode_json((boolean)$signed_request['page']['liked']) ?>;
</script>
```

To know if a user liked the page while he is on the splash page, you place a listener on a facebook event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function( response ) {`
  if ( response.match(/* RegExp matching your FB page url */) ) {
    // user liked!
  }
});
```

`response` is the URL liked, so you just have to compare it to your page url (`facebook.com/MyPage`) and then you know if a user clicked the like button in your application.

---

On a side note, generally the cleanest way to request user information is to login the user (OAuth), and pass requests directly from JS to the Open Graph (you use Angular anyway, so your app must be frontend based already). Your server shouldn't be used as a middle step between the Open Graph and your app, you'll duplicate code for without advantages.

This does not apply to the `page.liked` property, as it is a page property (not a user one) sent with the `signed_request` on app loading.

Comment: If you log the user in, you have to ask for `user_likes` permission as well to query if he likes the current page (or any, for that matter) – because the page info is _not_ part of the `signed_request` that login via `FB.login` returns.

Comment: @CBroe In the page like context, you're correct. I was explaining on a more generic way about the overall concept asked here (why data is not available in ajax requests).

Comment: The benefit of the `signed_request` within a page tab app is that you do not have to ask for `user_likes` permission to check whether the user likes that specific page – and since that permission allows access to _all_ the user’s likes, there is quite a chance that you won’t get that permission, whereas in the `signed_request` you get that info for free if you only want it for the page the app is running on.

Comment: @CBroe I edited my answer to be clearer. You're right my answer was confusing around the context of the question.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Thank you for a very extensive and insightful answer. I might miss something, but with the code–sample you provide, I see the following problem. Non-liking User visits tab, the info get's printed on page load, the user likes the page, but the info won't get updated until the page is reloaded, (witch is a problem in my case).

Comment: Oh, that's not an issue. You just have to listen to the `FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function( response ) {});` events. The `response` is the URL liked, so you just have to compare it to your page url (`facebook.com/MyPage`) and then you know if a user clicked the like button in your application.

Comment: As I said before, when the user visiting a page tab app likes the page via the like button on the top right corner … then the whole page gets reloaded automatically, so you will find the updated info in the signed_request, that gets posted to your app again.